# WP 8.1 application can't print on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, printing, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

Hello I have a application which is for Windows Phone 8.1 and it's working fine but when i try to install the app on Windows 10 Mobile everything is fine expect the module for bluetooth printing. It's not printing at all. So my question is how i can make the app to print on Windows 10 Mobile device?

Comment: Could your app print the document to the PDF? Could you see the printer in the user interface for printing content?

Comment: 1.No my app can't print the document to the PDF. Yes i can see the printer  but i use the printing module for printing receipts.

Comment: Could you select the first combox of the Printer in the printing content? Please select the Mircrosoft Print to PDF.

Comment: I can select every printer which is in the range of the phone's bluetooth module. When i tap the button for printing nothing happens. And my protocols are working fine on windows phone 8.1.